# Error while running .Net core 6.0 application in ubuntu using wine

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, wine, kernel32

We have .net framework based application which connects with backend using REST API. When we run this application using Wine on Ubuntu 20.04 it works perfectly well. Our requirement is that we need to covert this .net framework based application to .net core 6 first and then run using Wine on Ubuntu.
After this transformation, it works perfectly well in windows environemnt but when we run the application in ubuntu using Wine, it gives following error:

**Unhandled exception: unimplemented function KERNEL32.dll.RaiseFailFastException called in 32-bit code (0x7bc29f80).**

Our observations is that if the data size returned from the server is less than 4 MB, it works well. However if the size is greater than 4MB it is failing.

We are using Wine 7 version.

Appreciate any help on this.

Code snippet looks like follows:

var task = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();//System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response

var result = task.Result;

We get response code as 200 we have observed that it gets failed at task.Result statement.

Comment: .net 6 can compile native binaries for linux. Why do you need to run through wine?

Comment: do you still have some dependencies on windows binaries. if not then you don't need wine to run .net core application.

Comment: @gunr2171 Actually, it is a Winform App so it cannot be Published for LINUX. so we choose Wine to run it in Linux environment.